# bot for unwhitelisting people

Tags: python, discord.py, replit

I'm trying to make a bot for whitelisting and unwhitelisting people. I've use replit because it has easy DB - code will run in their DB. So I started making bot whitelist, which was easy. When I started unwhitelisting there was an error ...
when I was V.I.P bot it said that I wasn't. Please help me...
code :

```
@client.command()
async def unwhitelist(ctx, user):
    role = ctx.guild.get_role(893143464781422612)
    if role in ctx.author.roles:
        try:
            if len(db[str(user)]) != -1:
                del db[str(user)]
                await ctx.send(f'Succesfult deleted {str(user)} from V.I.P')
        except:
            await ctx.send(f'{str(user)} is not V.I.P')
    else:
        await ctx.send('U dont have Permission')
```

DB looks like this:

```
{'user', 'user1', 'user2'}
```

DB is plugin of replit so... don't get confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TLDR

Replace

```
try:
    if len(db[str(user)]) != -1:
        del db[str(user)]
        await ctx.send(f'Succesfult deleted {str(user)} from V.I.P')
except:
    await ctx.send(f'{str(user)} is not V.I.P')
```

with

```
if str(user) in db:
    db.remove(str(user))
    await ctx.send(f'Succesfult deleted {str(user)} from V.I.P')
else:
    await ctx.send(f'{str(user)} is not V.I.P')
```

### Explanation

Since you have

```
db = {'user', 'user1', 'user2'}
```

The variable `db` is a `set`, which is not subscriptable. So when your code runs `db[str(user)]` (as part of the `if` condition), you get the error

```
TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable
```

This error is caught in your `except` block, and so your program sends the message saying you are not VIP.